# issue restarting apache on centos 7

Tags: centos, apache-2.4

I am having trouble restarting apache. All I did was just copy some pulled changes of my html files from git to the home directory.

this is what my apache status saids :

```
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-08-25 02:23:28 EDT; 3min 23s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 2249 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2247 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2247 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

here are my error logs :

```
[Wed Aug 23 15:36:17.712634 2017] [core:notice] [pid 8843] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Wed Aug 23 15:36:17.713733 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 8843] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Aug 23 15:36:17.740841 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 8843] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Aug 23 15:36:17.742425 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 8843] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Aug 23 15:36:17.771370 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8843] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 23 15:36:17.771406 2017] [core:notice] [pid 8843] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed Aug 23 15:46:29.321240 2017] [:error] [pid 8843] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Wed Aug 23 15:46:39.336281 2017] [:error] [pid 8843] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Wed Aug 23 15:46:49.346828 2017] [:error] [pid 8843] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Wed Aug 23 15:46:59.358148 2017] [:error] [pid 8843] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Wed Aug 23 15:47:09.383503 2017] [:error] [pid 8843] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Wed Aug 23 15:47:19.395250 2017] [:error] [pid 8843] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Wed Aug 23 15:47:29.406741 2017] [:error] [pid 8843] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Wed Aug 23 15:47:39.427361 2017] [:error] [pid 8843] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Wed Aug 23 15:47:49.448852 2017] [:error] [pid 8843] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Wed Aug 23 15:47:59.494933 2017] [:error] [pid 8843] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Wed Aug 23 15:48:09.513882 2017] [:error] [pid 8843] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Wed Aug 23 15:48:19.527063 2017] [:error] [pid 8843] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Wed Aug 23 15:48:29.541808 2017] [:error] [pid 8843] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Wed Aug 23 15:48:39.553860 2017] [:error] [pid 8843] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Wed Aug 23 15:48:49.568994 2017] [:error] [pid 8843] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Wed Aug 23 15:48:59.582883 2017] [:error] [pid 8843] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
[Wed Aug 23 15:49:09.602016 2017] [:error] [pid 8843] AH00000: sd_notifyf returned an error -111
```

Comment: And the apache error log?

Comment: Do you have any error in error logs?

Comment: Have you tried `systemctl restart httpd.service` ?  And checked for syntax errors with `apachectl configest`?

Comment: SELinux is enabled. Can you check also files `/var/log/audit/audit.log` or `/var/log/audit.log`

Comment: there is a lot of stuff in /var/log/audit/audit.log. what should I be looking for?